# insert to wxListCtrl from a " map<string, map<string ,string> > "

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, listctrl

I have a wxWidgets project that contains 2 .cpp files. Firstly the purpose of it is to get data from 3 wxComboBox into a map container and then insert these data into a wxListCtrl.

The last part of it isn't working, and I can't figure it out why, because the insertion seems correct to me (void ViewRefresh)

```
- ItemsInStock is a map<string, map<string ,string> >

- Category, ItemID and Name are wxComboBox

- RaktarLista_a and RaktarLista_b are wxListCtrl objects
```

the relevant contain of the hasznaltmobilbolt.cpp:

```
int HasznaltmobilBolt::UploadNewItem(string tipus,string azonosito, string nev)
{
   int i;
        map<string, string> m;
        m.insert({tipus,nev});
        ItemsInStock.insert({azonosito,m});
        return 1;
}
```

and the relevant contain of the wxkitMain.cpp:

```
void wxkitFrame::OnAddButtonClick(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    string tipus=Category->GetLabel().ToStdString();
    string azonosito=ItemID->GetLabelText().ToStdString();
    string nev=Name->GetLabelText().ToStdString();
    int i=H.UploadNewItem(azonosito, nev, tipus);

        ViewRefresh(H.ItemsInStock);
        *Message << "Adding new item is done.\n";
}

 void wxkitFrame::ViewRefresh(map<string, map<string ,string> > Map)
{
RaktarLista_a->ClearAll();
RaktarLista_a->InsertColumn(0,"Azonosito", wxLIST_FORMAT_CENTER, 100);
RaktarLista_a->InsertColumn(1,"Nev", wxLIST_FORMAT_CENTER, 100);
RaktarLista_a->InsertColumn(2,"Tipus", wxLIST_FORMAT_CENTER,100);
RaktarLista_b->ClearAll();
RaktarLista_b->InsertColumn(0,"Azonosito", wxLIST_FORMAT_CENTER, 100);
RaktarLista_b->InsertColumn(1,"Nev", wxLIST_FORMAT_CENTER, 100);
RaktarLista_b->InsertColumn(2,"Tipus", wxLIST_FORMAT_CENTER,100);

int i=0;
for (map<string, map<string ,string> >::iterator it_azonosito=Map.begin();     
it_azonosito!=Map.end();it_azonosito++)
{ for(map<string ,string>::iterator it_nev=it_azonosito->second.begin();    
it_nev!=it_azonosito->second.end();it_nev++)
    {
        RaktarLista_a->InsertItem(i, it_azonosito->first);
        RaktarLista_a->SetItem(i, 1, it_nev->first);
        RaktarLista_a->SetItem(i, 2,it_nev->second);
        RaktarLista_b->InsertItem(i, it_azonosito->first);
        RaktarLista_b->SetItem(i, 1, it_nev->first);
        RaktarLista_b->SetItem(i, 2,it_nev->second);
        i++;
    }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit difficult to say without a better analysis, but I would try replacing the ViewRefresh by a reference. I cannot really figure out if you have a valid operator= or copy-ctor to handle the passing by value operation.

Just try changing to:

```
void wxkitFrame::ViewRefresh(map<string, map<string ,string> > &Map)
{
    ...
}
```

An enhancement could be adding a const to protect the input argument from accidental changes, but then you need to change your **iterator** to **const_iterator**. For example:

```
void wxkitFrame::ViewRefresh(const map<string, map<string ,string> > &Map)
{
    ...
}
```

A bit of a guess, but I hope I could help you.

Comment: thank you! :) unfortunately the problem isn't solved, but I'm going to try some further debugging